# crop image to a certain size in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to crop a image to a certain.

I have tried using

```
add_image_size( 'other', 105, 70, true );
 $imageString.= '<div><a href="' . $linkstring . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'other;) . '</a></div>';
```

But it does not seem to crop to that exact dimension.

Any Ides?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally you add image sizes into your functions.php file.

```
//post thumbnail support
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );

function theme_setup() {
      if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
        add_image_size( 'other', 105, 70, true ); 
    }
}
```

Then, once in place, for all new image uploads wordpress will create an image at that size.

If you want to create these image sizes for already uploaded images, have a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, get_the_post_thumbnail doesn't always work if you use custom image size added with add_image_size.

I'd advise you to use add_image_size, but get the image throught wp_get_attachment_image_src like this:

```
$imageurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, "other" );

$imageString.= '<div><a href="' . $linkstring . '"><img src="' . $imageurl[0] . '"/></a></div>';
```

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image_src does not take a post ID as a parameter. it takes an attachment id. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 0):

The functions related to image resizing and cropping are all placed in media.php.

For example, start reading about image_resize_dimensions which will also give you dimensions for cropping. Those dimensions can then be used with imagecopyresampled.