# Custom image size WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image

I'm building a custom blog listing page for a Wordpress site and trying to use a custom image size. The height of the images should be a hard 300px. All images are taller than this, so not worried about smaller images.

The width I would like to be 500px. This is where I'm having issues. I'm trying to use the Wordpress add_image_size function for this, but I keep getting a crop of exact dimensions.

Example, I use the following code, and it gives me an exact 300x300 pixel image:

```
add_image_size( 'blog-two', 500, 300);
```

I've even tried adding the hard crop value to this and not getting the desired result of a 500x300 pixel cropped image.

```
add_image_size( 'blog-two', 500, 300, true);
```

Is this function depreciated? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the add_image_size() to your functions.php file, if so your code should function properly?

There might be more guidance in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012421/crop-image-to-a-certain-size-in-wordpress).

Comment: Yes I have, that's what's puzzling. It's like this function is resizing, but not cropping. To compensate, I've made size 25% larger, then I'm using CSS to hide parts of the image that fall outside of the specified area......i.e. `DIV width=500px, overflow=hidden`

Comment: I suppose that is a decent work around. For images of varying sizes, has defining the div width also solved the cropping problem?